# Animating a HTML Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I've been trying to animate this drop down menu for ages, spending hours editing everything I thought was relevant and it still doesn't work. I have a few linked pages, the source code in HTML5, and several bootstrap pages as well as one styling sheet. Here is the source code:

```
<div class = "navigation"> 

        <button class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle = "dropdown"  id = "navButton"> Navigation</button>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu" id = "dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Picture Gallery</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Families</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Latest News</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Local Services</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Housing Development</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

I wont copy the whole of each bootstrap files for obvious reasons, but here is my StyleSheet for the dropdown itself:

```
#navButton{
background-color: #0783FF;
border: none;
color: #FFF;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
width: 100%;

}
#navButton:hover{
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
content: 'a-chevron-down';
transition: 0.5s;

}
#dropdown ul li:after{
    background-color: #0783FF;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    width: 100%;

}
#dropdown{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0669CC;
    color: #FFF !important;

}
```

The dropdown itself works fine, when I click it the menu appears with all `buttons responding properly. The only issue is that I want it to 'slide' down` rather than just appear. I've looked at several different tutorials and I still can't figure out what the issue is. I'm not sure whether the animating code goes in my style sheet or the bootstrap.css sheet.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This demo shows you an animation example with only `css`. Hopefully it's usefull for you.

```css
#navButton {
  background-color: #0783FF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navButton:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  content: 'a-chevron-down';
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown ul li:after {
  background-color: #0783FF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  width: 100%;
}

#dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0669CC;
  color: #FFF !important;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -80px, 0px);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s, opacity 0.3s ease 0s, height 0s linear 0.35s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1000px, 0px);
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.navigation {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation.open #dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navigation">

  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navButton"> Navigation</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Picture Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Families</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Latest News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Local Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Housing Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work but I'm using an older version of jQuery, I'm using 1.12.0 and moving to the newer version breaks the entire site. The button stops working completely if I just use this code in the old version, is there a way of doing this in the version that I am using?

Comment: I updated the answer to an older version of jQuery. As you can see, it still works. In other words, this technique has nothing to do with jQuery. So your problem should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Turn visibility off on your CSS file for the menu or with JQuery, then you can use JQuery to detect the hover event and turn on the visibility on your menu and animate it.

Something like this:

```
$("#dropdown").hide();

$("#myMenu").mouseover(function () {
    $("#dropdown").slideDown('slow');
});

$("#myMenu").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#dropdown").slideUp('slow');
});
```

and change your HTML into something like this (wrap the menu with a DIV and give it an ID, this is for mouse event detection purposes):

```
     <div id="myMenu">
        <button class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle = "dropdown"  id = "navButton"> Navigation</button>
        <ul class = "dropdown-menu" id = "dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Picture Gallery</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Families</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Latest News</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Local Services</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Housing Development</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```